# Why can't you have multiple parent elements in a component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react and if I write this code in the `return()` I get this error:

> JSX expressions must have one parent element.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="fixed-top-nav">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Crypto Currency</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>

        <Jumbotron fluid className="mb-0"></Jumbotron>

    );
  }
}
```

I understand if I surround the below code with a `<div>` like the code below, it works perfectly fine.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="fixed-top-nav">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Crypto Currency</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>

        <Jumbotron fluid className="mb-0"></Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder why can't you have multiple indirect parents in a single component in react?

Comment: because they want you to have one parent. If you do not want the div, you can wrap it with a fragment. You need to realize that JSX is being compiled into a "create element line" behind the scenes so it is expecting one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how JSX gets compiled into Javascript:

`const myJSXValue = <span>Some text</span>`

becomes

`const myJSXValue = React.createElement("span", null, "Some text");`

In other words it is creating a function call for the element, which can then be passed around as good ol' JavaScript.

JSX depends on single function call, even if that function call ends up being nested with more, so that it can be passed around and returned from functions. How many values can a JavaScript function return? Just one :) Even if, again, that single value includes other values, such as with an array.

A wrapped example:

`const myJSXValue = <><span>Some text</span><span>Some more text</span></>`

becomes

`const myJSXValue = React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, React.createElement("span", null, "Some text"), React.createElement("span", null, "Some more text"));`

As you can see, since it is wrapped with a single parent, the `myJSXValue` gets assigned a single function call. *That* function call includes additional calls, but at the outer layer you have 1 value. Similarly, when you have a component that returns a JSX value, you get to return 1 single value.

So you at least need a dummy parent element to wrap your children into a single function call that can be passed around (i.e. returned from a component).

The simplest way is just to use React.Fragment, which can be abbreviated as in the example above with `<></>`

Comment: I don't agree with this. JSX could have detected top level adjacent fragments and automatically nest them into a transient container like React.Fragment. They've chosen to not go down that path. It isn't because it is impossible.

Comment: The underlying JavaScript reason remains the same though, regardless of whether they fix it for you or not.

Comment: The javascript reason is irrelevant. They could make it work like OP wants if they wanted.

Comment: That's a little pedantic, but sure. You could also say that about most anything with frameworks. Why does framework F based on language L do thing T? Because L expects T and F didn't hide it from you.

Comment: Well explained, now I have an understanding of why you must have just one indirect parent!

Answer (score 2):

You can! React Fragment was made for this.

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can read more about it in the official docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: So then why do you have to have a Fragment as a parent?

Comment: There is merely a syntax detail of [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). Before React Fragment, this detail led to a meaningful shortcoming (you had to litter the DOM with meaningless `div`s). But now that you have Fragment, you can ignore this as just syntax choice.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [React Documentation for render method](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%E2%80%9Crender%20prop%E2%80%9D%20refers,implementing%20its%20own%20render%20logic.), a React element (or null) is expected to be returned

React builds and maintains virtual DOM in order to function. Hence only one element is expected which will be treated as Root for that particular component.

We definitely will come across such scenarios, where we may have to return multiple elements. We can do this using by wrapping the group of element to be returned by [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) or [<></>](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) (v16.2+)